# How Turn off Windows Phone keys vibration Windows 10?

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, navigation-key

I just update my Nokia Lumia 830 to Windows 10 Technical Preview, but I can't disable Windows keys vibration

How I can fix this ?

Comment: choose an answer? :)

Answer (score 9):

Go to Settings > Extras > Touch. There you should see the option to turn it on or off.

Comment: Have same issue but touch isn't available in Extras. Did hard reset as upgrade from 8 to 10 had lots of bugs but now have vibrate on back and Windows buttons. It didn't do it with upgrade install but can't find any way to turn it off. It still does it when vibrate is off. Any help gratefully received as I really hate it as a feature and it makes enough noise that it would be noticeable in meetings.

Comment: I have Touch installed, it has 'Vibrate' set to Off, but the back and search buttons both still vibrate.
Grrr!

Answer (score 2):

Try Updating Extras. I faced same problem on my Lumia 535 when I did upgrade on Windows 10 but through official **Upgrade Advisor app**. This caused some bugs in extras just after upgradation but when I updated Extras from the Store app it resolved almost 95% issues. See this . Updated Touch successfully turn vibration on and off.

[image]

Comment: This should be accepted answer IMHO :)